# c# winform to select a web page dropdown option

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a application to fill out web forms and I can fill out the text fields but have not been able to figure out how to handle selecting from a drop-down list. 
I am able to get it to place the Focus on the element but not able to get set the drop down option.  This is what I have been trying to do to select the drop-down.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("BirthMonth").Focus();
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("BirthMonth").InvokeMember("click");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the "SelectedIndex" property to the integer index of the entry you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building an aspx web page, you can use the SelectedValue attribute. For eg, DropDownlist.SelectedValue.toString(). That should give you the selected value from the web page.

Comment: I am using windows form application.